# Add extra column/field to RavenDB collection via RQL in Raven Studio

Tags: updates, ravendb, ravendb-studio

I'm trying to update the entire collection by adding an extra field to each entity. This *doesn't* do the trick:

```
from things 
as t
update 
{
    put( id(t), "NewField");
}
```

Can someone help out with the syntax please ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just do:

```
from things as t
update {
    t.nameOfNewField = "valueOfNewField"
}
```

See:

https://ravendb.net/learn/inside-ravendb-book/reader/4.0/2-zero-to-ravendb#patching-documents