# Remove field from collection in RavenDB Studio

Tags: ravendb, ravendb-studio

I am trying to remove a property (whose addition to the documents I asked for help with, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60413448/add-extra-column-field-to-ravendb-collection-via-rql-in-raven-studio) ), using RavenDB Studio (I accidentally added them to the wrong database collection...).

Again, I'm stuck on the syntax. Also - I can't believe nobody has had the intention of doing this until now - at least intense googling couldn't produce anything useful. The official documentation is also terse on this subject, to say the least.
Aside: Why is DDL in RavenDB (and presumably other NoSQL DBs) so cumbersome ?

I tried various versions of

```
from things  as t
update {
    delete t.field 
}
```

none of which work, and some of them don't even compile.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With Patching - removing a document field can be done this way from the **Client** code:

**Single document:**

```
session.Advanced.Defer(new PatchCommandData(
    id: "yourDocumentID",
    changeVector: null,
    patch: new PatchRequest
    {
        Script = @"delete this.fieldToDelete"
    },
    patchIfMissing: null));

session.SaveChanges();
```

See: [Patching - Removing Property](https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/4.2/Csharp/client-api/operations/patching/single-document#remove-property)

**Multiple documents:**

```
var operation = store
    .Operations
    .Send(new PatchByQueryOperation("from things update { delete this.field; }"));

operation.WaitForCompletion();
```

Example was taken from [here](https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/4.2/Csharp/client-api/operations/patching/set-based#updating-a-collection-name)

**For RQL simply use:**

```
from things 
update { 
   delete this.field; 
}
```